# Mobius function related series and Dirichlet summation

Tags: riemann-zeta, divergent-series, dirichlet-series, mobius-function, summation-method

A well known identities of rare beauty is that:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}=\frac 1{\zeta(s)}$$

Where $\mu(n)$ is the Mobius function and $\zeta(s)$ is the Riemann Zeta function. So, in the context of summability theory/divergent series summation one can easily deduce that:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(n)=1-1-1+0-1+1-1+0+0+\dots=\frac 1{\zeta(0)}=-2$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(n)n=1-2-3+0-5+6-7+0+0+\dots=\frac 1{\zeta(-1)}=-12$$

Or I'm not supposed to jump to that conclusion ? If I'm doing this correctly I can generalize the statement for general odd integers as:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(n)n^k=1-2^k-3^k+0-5^k+6^k-7^k+0+0+\dots=\frac 1{\zeta(-k)}=-\frac {k+1}{B_{k+1}}$$

Where $B_k$ are the Bernoulli numbers. However my problem is for even values of $k$ for which we have $\zeta(-k)=0$ and the situation became pretty messy. How can I solve this problem and for example assign in some way a finite value to:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(n)n^2=1-4-9+0-25+36-49+0+0+\dots=?$$

Comment: Replace $S(k) \rightarrow \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \frac{1}{2}\left[S(k+\epsilon) + S(k-\epsilon)\right] $

Comment: Could you please elaborate further ? @CountIblis

Comment: The zeta function has simple zeros at negative even integers, so the reciprocal of the zeta function has simple poles there. This means that the summation S(k) near an even integer will have a singularity of the form $S(2n +\epsilon) \sim \frac{1}{\epsilon}$. So, if you replace S(k) by the limit of the average of $S(k+\epsilon)$ and $S(k-\epsilon)$, you cancel out the pole while not affecting the other values of S(k).

Comment: why would you want to assign "some value" to any sequences ? learn instead : complex analysis, the Cauchy integral formula, analytic continuation, etc.

Comment: @user1952009 I simply cut short the description of the question. I think it is pretty clear in the theory of divergent series that I'm not trying to assign an arbitrary value to the original series.

Comment: you are if you don't get the machinery behind those summation methods. so my advice is too study complex analysis